# Ambiguous behavior of For loop in Golang

Tags: for-loop, go

I want make some simple loop like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i uint32 // code bellow works fine with int32
    for i = 31; i >= 0; i-- {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

But this loop is endless, if `i` has type `uint32`. If `i` is `int32` it`s ok.

How I can break this loop, if `i` has type `uint32` without checking `if i == 0`?

Comment: Well... i can't be negative so you **have** to check when it goes to 0.

Comment: Or you use an int32.

Comment: All values of an unsigned integer is positive...therefore your condition will always be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` is of type `uint32`, so once it reaches `0`, decrementing again will result in the max value of `uint32`. Change the loop condition to check for that:

```
var i uint32 // code bellow works fine with int32
for i = 31; i != 0xffffffff; i-- {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/T10ZUtmlFLQ).

Or use the `math.MaxUint32` constant:

```
var i uint32 // code bellow works fine with int32
for i = 31; i != max.MaxUint32; i-- {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Or use the `^uint32(0)` expression, where the `^` operator is the bitwise complement operator, applied on `0` will give you a value where all the bits are ones: the max value for `uint32`.

Although if you look at the code, it's not intuitive, hard to understand. So you should use alternatives where this is not required and are more straightforward, such as using `int32` and checking for `i >= 0`, or use an upward loop, such as:

```
for i := uint32(0); i < 32; i++ {
    fmt.Println(31 - i)
}
```

Or offset the loop variable's range with +1, so you can test for `i >= 1` or `i > 0`:

```
for i := uint32(32); i > 0; i-- {
    fmt.Println(i-1)
}
```

Comment: You forgot the disclaimer: "don't do that to keep the code readable".

Comment: Thanks for the constant max.MaxUint32. I was looking for her :) Solved.

Comment: `i != ^uint32(0)` would also do without resorting to importing `math`.

Comment: @kostix True, I forgot about that :)